# How can I make an image loop infinitely in Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm hoping this question will be easy to answer, I have 2 pictures of identical shape and size, I'd like them to infinitely loop from one to the other as soon as the app starts. It would be similar to an animated gif, they wouldn't move or rotate, just loop repeatedly, and very vast (over 10 loops per second at least). A way to adjust the speed in milliseconds would be a big plus.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`FrameAnimation`](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame). There is example in docs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```